# Sitecore Query to get the latest item under a folder

Tags: sitecore

I need to get the latest sitecore item created under specific folder as a data source. How I need to achieve this using sitecore query ?
Here I tried :

```
fast:/sitecore/content/Home/About//*[@@templatename = 'Artice']
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is _not_ a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first by doing some research on the subject and making an attempt to write the code. If you have issues with that code, then feel free to ask a question requesting debugging help. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I know that one. But I don't know how to proceed this that is why I am asking this.

Comment: You want to query child items under its self? query:self::

Comment: Nope. Latest created item

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by a Sitecore Fast Query and a LINQ statement, the following code sample retrieves the last updated item from *MyFolder* folder:

```
Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content/home/myfolder/*").OrderByDescending(w => w.Statistics.Updated).Take(1);
```